# `409 Conflict` response: {"code":"MissingParameter","message":"You must provide a user key."}

Tags: laravel, rest, api

So i am messing about with the Marvel API and i have been getting this error and i cannot find any trace of it anywhere.

```
`409 Conflict` response: {"code":"MissingParameter","message":"You must provide a user key."}
```

I have checked through the API Documentation and i cannot find anything about a user key.

Here is my code; I am using Laravel with Guzzle.

```
$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://gateway.marvel.com:80/v1/public/comics', [
        'apikey' => $apikey,
        'ts' => $now,
        'hash' => md5($now . $privateKey . $apikey),

    ]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$query = http_build_query([
     'apikey' => $apikey, 
     'ts' => $now, 
     'hash' => md5($now . $privateKey . $apikey)
]);

$url = 'http://gateway.marvel.com:80/v1/public/comics?' . $query;

$res = $client->request('GET', $url);
```

**update**

Looks like you just need to set the [query](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#query) option in the request.

```
$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://gateway.marvel.com:80/v1/public/comics', [
    'query' => [
        'apikey' => $apikey, 
        'ts' => $now, 
        'hash' => md5($now . $privateKey . $apikey)
    ]
]);
```

Comment: You are a star. Thank you so so much. This sorted it.

Answer (score -1):

Changed the upload folder, the problem is solved.